# counting every occurrence of parenthesis in strings, ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sdk

I made some codes to  count every parenthesis from some string,

Is there any simpler way?

```
NSCharacterSet *parenthesis = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"];
parenthesis = [parenthesis invertedSet];
NSArray *arr = [someString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:parenthesis];
NSInteger count = 0;
for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++)  {
    if([[arr objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@")"])
        count++;
}
NSLog(@"count is %d", count);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to walk through all characters in the string anyway, why not simply

```
NSUInteger count = 0;
for (NSInteger i = someString.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    unichar ch = [someString characterAtIndex:i];
    count += (ch == '(' || ch == ')');
}
```

This uses fewer classes, much easier to read, and uses less CPU to perform the calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions to the rescue

```
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[()]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:someString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [someString length])];
```

This uses framework functionality, meaning it has been tuned for string manipulations, as well as being clear in its operation. It's flexible, if you only need to check particular substrings. It is also very maintainable, only the regex needs changing if you need to count other types of characters.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply !